# Masking subdirectories and pages for my website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, masking

I want to mask some of the subdirectories and pages for my website. For example:

I want to change
www.example.com/blog.php?post=post1

to
www.example.com/blog

or something similar to that. I have seen examples about redirecting and such but that doesn't seem to work for what I want and I would like to stay away from iframes if possible. I just want the address bar to not reflect my internal directory structure and page names. I want it to keep showing /blog while they are moving from post to post. Thanks.

P.S. I am not using wordpress or any other CMS or blogging system.

Comment: How is your website set up? If you have nginx in front of it this is almost trivial. Depending on what you use to serve content, different frameworks have different ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache mod_rewrite for that.

[Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php)

And if You don't want to have the same url on blog-post/article change, but to display different content, all I can think of this moment is by using either POST method or browser cookies, but, that would require a lot of page reloads, and it simply is not recommended for wide use. If You are building per_se (one person only) panel or similar, than url doesn't matter that much, but, speaking of blog..

It is quite reasonable to hide .php extension or url query index/key, but not what You would like to accomplish.

Like I said, it is possible, but `Luke .. don't do that`. 
Blog should be bookmarkable on each and every @stop, and that happens just because of unique urls and hash values. Without these two, no hyperlinking possible *(not to mention seo penals and flaws + dozen of other unwanted obstacles, page caching for instance).